# crontab can not find openpyxl python module

Tags: python-2.7, centos, cron, openpyxl, centos7

Hi I am writing a program with python on CentOS 7.1. I am using "crontab" to run this program execution. I am using one python module, openpyxl. My program creates an excel. This program **executes just fine** when I run it from console, with python command. I am using Python 2.7.10.

But, when I tell the crontab to run this program. It is showing the following error. 
N.B. crontab is executing my program, fine.

```
...
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
ImportError: No module named openpyxl
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I did not give the absolute path of my python. It should be like this -

```
44 11 * * * /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /root/report_downloadable.py >/root/downloadable_error.log 2>&1
```